# jquery: check for duplicates in multiple lists

Tags: jquery, duplicates

I have the following code:

```
<ul id="listOne">
    <li>John</li>
    <li>James</li>
    <li>Mary</li>
</ul>

<ul id="listTwo">
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Mark</li>
    <li>Mary</li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is hide any objects in the 2nd list if they are already in the 1st list.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 5):

There may be a slightly better way, but this is what came to mind first:

```
var firstList = [];
$("#listOne li").each(function() {
    firstList.push($(this).text());
});
$("#listTwo li").filter(function() {
    return firstList.indexOf($(this).text()) > -1;
}).remove();
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/7DGHd/). It builds an array of the text of the items in the first list, then [filters](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the items of the second list to return only those which are also in the first list, and then removes the matched items from the DOM.

Comment: Damn you, was just in the middle of typing that ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) the first list to an array then [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the second list values that have matching text and hide those like this:

```
var values = $('#listOne li').map(function() { 
    return $(this).text();
}).get();

$('#listTwo li').filter(function() {
    return $.inArray($(this).text(), values) !== -1;
}).hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/unTMz/